# Are these strings concatenated correctly for fopen()?

Tags: c, unix, fopen, strcpy, strcat

I want to concatenate the two strings `config_path` and `config_file` and pass that string into `fopen()`. The problem is that `fopen()` returns an error even though I am 100% the file exists. As a matter of fact, I print the string in the command line before passing it into `fopen()`, and if I copy this string directly into my source code, then `fopen()` finds the file. What's the problem here?

Command Line Output

```
config: /nfs/stak/students/m/morriluk/.myshellrc|header: HOME
Unable to open configuration file: No such file or directory
```

Source Code

```
  1 #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200908L
  2 #define SHELL_BSIZE 1024
  3 #define BSIZE 128
  4 #define CONFIG_FILE "/.myshellrc"
  5
  6 #include <stdio.h>
  7 #include <stdlib.h>
  8 #include <string.h>
  9 #include <dirent.h>
 10 #include <unistd.h>
 11 #include <errno.h>
 12 #include <sys/types.h>
 13 #include <sys/wait.h>
 14
 15 char *WARNINGS = "0";
 16
 17 int main()
 18 {
 19     int i;
 20     char buffer[BSIZE], *arg = NULL;
 21     FILE *f;
 22     char *config_path, *str, *config_file = CONFIG_FILE;
 23     char *header = "HOME";
 24
 25     config_path = getenv("HOME");
 26
 27     str = malloc((strlen(config_path)+strlen(config_file))*sizeof(char));
 28     strcpy(str, config_path);
 29     strcat(str, config_file);
 30
 31     printf("config: %s|header: %s\n", str, header);
 32
 33     for (i = 0; i < BSIZE; i++)
 34         buffer[i] = '\0';
 35
 36     if ((f = fopen(str, "r")) != NULL){
 37
 38     }
 39     else {
 40         perror("Unable to open configuration file");
 41     }
 42     return 0;
 43 }
```

Comment: You didn't reserve room for a null terminator in `str`, did you?

Comment: Add `1` to the buffer for terminating `0`. Make sure `config_path` ends with '\\'. Try to print `str`.

Comment: It was that simple? Q_Q I just wasted 4 hours on this... Thanks a ton for your help

Answer (score 0):

Example program to open File by getting Path from ENV

```
OpenFile()
{
string filename;
FILE      *fp;
filename = string(getenv("HOME")) + "/FileName"; //Home - Configpath, Replace File Name
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fp == NULL ) cout<<"filename read failed"<<endl;
/* Write Code to perform task on File */
fclose(fp); //Close handle 
}
```

To test you can make any random file and try if fopen works for other file in same path

```
if(fp=fopen("/nfs/stak/students/m/morriluk/TESTFILE","r"))
```

If above code does not solve problem, let me know unix flavor and absolute file path with name